# Mapping discrete numbers

Tags: general-topology, number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I would like to find a way to map the natural numbers, $\mathbb{N}$, to integers, $\mathbb{Z}$, and vice-versa.

An analogous solution for continuous numbers would be using the $\log()$ and $\exp()$ function to map $\mathbb{R}^+$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and vice-versa.

Please advise! Thanks :)

Comment: $f\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}:\mathbb{N}$ then $f(x)=|x|$.

Comment: $g\rightarrow\mathbb{N}:\mathbb{Z}$ then $g(x)=(-1)^x\cdot x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want a a bijection, not just any mapping.

Any enumeration of $\mathbb{Z}$ as a sequence is a bijection $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$; just associate the natural number $n$ to the $n$th integer in the $\mathbb{Z}$-sequence. One (of many) such sequences is $0,1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,\ldots$.

Comment: Thanks all for the prompt answers to an embarrassing question.
@angryavian or anyone else for that matter, how about for a finite subset of $\mathbb{Z}$, for example $x\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, is it possible to map it it to $\mathbb{Z}$?
Hope my question doesnt sound too stupid!

Comment: You may answer the question over at: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1866128/mapping-finite-discrete-numbers-to-the-infinite-set

Answer (score 0):

To explicitly write angryavian's answer $f: \Bbb{N}\rightarrow\Bbb{Z}$ is defined as

$$f(n)=\begin{cases}
n/2, & \text{if $n$ is even} \\
-(n+1)/2, & \text{if $n$ is odd}
\end{cases}$$