# Mapping finite discrete numbers to the infinite set

Tags: general-topology, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

This is an extension of my earlier question: [Mapping discrete numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1866056/mapping-discretenumbers)

Given that we can "map" $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ via a bijection, I then wondered if it is possible to map a small subset of $\mathbb{Z}$, i.e., $X\in\{-1,0,1,2,3\}$, back to $\mathbb{Z}$, just as one would map $x\in(-1,3)$ to $y\in\mathbb{R}$ using the function, $f(x) = -\log\|\frac{4}{x+1}-1\|$?

Comment: How do you think you can map five elements to an infinite number of elements?  The range necessarily cannot have more elements than the domain.

Comment: You can't create a bijection between a finite set to an infinite set.

Comment: Hi @Gregory Grant and @Q the Platypus, thanks for your responses. I thought that this may be so but my mathematical vocabulary is too limited to better phrase my question. If mapping is not possible, would there be anyway to establish some form of relationship between these finite set of numbers to $\mathbb{Z}$? An impossible answer is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to create a non bijective map between the set you give and $\mathbb{Z} $.  The simplest map would be $ f = \{ (-1, -1), (0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3) \} $.  Basically mapping each element of $X$ to it's equivalent in $\mathbb{Z}$.  However this function isn't surjective (there are elements in $\mathbb{Z}$ that are not in the image of $f$) so it can't be bijective.

In general you can only have a bijection between two sets if the number of elements in both sets is equal.

Comment: Thanks again @Q the Platypus. Then is it possible to map $X$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ as follows: $f = \{ (-1,\{-\infty,\ldots,-1\}),(0,0),(1,1),(2,2),(3,\{3,\ldots,\infty\})\}$ ? If so what would this kind of mapping be called?

Comment: That wouldn't be a mapping.  Both sides of a mapping have to be the same type.

You can define a relationship like this $ f = \{ (-1, -1), (-1, -2) ..., (0,0),(1,1),(2,2),(3,3), (3,4), ...\} $ however this is not a map because to be a map each domain element can't be associated with multiple elements in the co-domain.

Comment: ok got it. thnx for your help!